# convert minutes::rep to hours::rep

Tags: c++, linux, date, c++11, c++-chrono

How should I proceed to convert `std::chrono::minutes::rep` type value to hours representation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
    minutes::rep time = 4;
    std::cout << time;  // outputs as minutes, need in hours

    // duration cast doesn't seems to work here because it
    // needs minutes instead of minutes::rep probably

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `minutes::rep` and not just `minutes`?

Comment: `<chrono>` tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> minutes::rep time = 4;
> std::cout << time;  // outputs as minutes, need in hours
> ```

Because `time` is just an (implementation-defined) integer type, it has nothing to do with `minutes` or `hours`, and doesn't know anything about underlying time representation.

You want to stay in the `duration` realm:

```
minutes time{4};
auto as_hours = std::duration_cast<hours>(time);
std::cout << as_hours.count(); // prints 0
```

Or, likely:

```
auto as_hours_dbl = std::duration_cast<duration<double, hours::period>>(time);
std::cout << as_hours_dbl.count(); // prints 0.0666667
```